# Acceder arreglo JSON Laravel

Tags: laravel, json, laravel-5

Hola estoy conectandome a través de la API de woocommerce a una tienda y quiero extraer datos, creo que me llegan en formato JSON, pero no se bien como iterarlo.

**Controlador:**

```
$productos = response()->json($woocommerce->get('products'));

return view('index', compact('productos'));
```

**En la vista:**

```
@foreach ($productos as $item)
    @php
        dd($item)
    @endphp     
@endforeach
```

Si hago el `dd` en `$productos` me trae lo siguiente:

```
  #data: "[{"id":444,"name":"Disco","slug":"disco","permalink":"link\/","date_created":"2019-10-31T18:23 ▶"
  #callback: null
  #encodingOptions: 0
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag {#1262 ▶}
  #content: "[{"id":444,"name":"Disco","slug":"disco-","permalink":"https:\/\/link\/","date_created":"2019-10-31T18:23 ▶"
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
  +original: array:10 [▼
    0 => {#1130 ▶}
    1 => {#1143 ▶}
    2 => {#1156 ▶}
    3 => {#1170 ▶}
    4 => {#1185 ▶}
    5 => {#1196 ▶}
    6 => {#1209 ▶}
    7 => {#1222 ▶}
    8 => {#1235 ▶}
    9 => {#1248 ▶}
```

Si hago `dd` en `$item`:

```
  #computedCacheControl: array:2 [▶]
  #cookies: []
  #headerNames: array:3 [▶]
  #headers: array:3 [▶]
  #cacheControl: []
```

Donde quiero acceder es lo que muestra la variable $productos pero donde pone `+original: array 10` es donde están todos los productos. ¿Como puedo iterar los datos?

**Solución gracias a @BetaM:**

Haciendo un foreach dentro del principal:

```
  @foreach ($productos->original as $item)
     <li>{{ $item->name }} - {{ $item->price }}</li>    
  @endforeach
```

Comment: @BetaM no entiendo con lo de principal? A que te refieres?

Comment: Con que variables??

Comment: Pues si arroja datos pero solo del primero, tendria que traer en el `dd` todos los que hay no @BetaM , No he dicho nada ala hacer {{ $item->name }} me trae todos

Comment: Perdona ahora borro este comentario! pero ponemos una respuesta o pongo la respuesta en mi pregunta @BetaM

Comment: Una última pregunta y ahora borro comentarios y modifico la pregunta, Una vez haciendo esto `foreach($item->original as $elemento)` ya puedo acceder a todo los datos, pero y si hay otro nivel? Es decir hay otra cosa que  necesito acceder que es: `+"shipping_lines": array:1 [▼` y dentro está el producto comprado, he probado así: `dd($item->line_items)` y me trae lo que hay dentro, pero si quiero imprimirlo así: {{ $item->line_items->name }} me devuelve error @BetaM

Comment: Pero si necesito datos de los dos niveles en una misma fila, por ejemplo un `<li>`@BetaM - Nada ya he visto que se puede acceder al foreach anterior, voy a modificar la pregunta y borrar comentarios, gracias de nuevo

Comment: Como esta tu relacion en tus modelos?

Comment: Hola @Dohko19 ya esta la solución en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, prueba utilizando el operado '->', esto llama a las propiedades de un objeto Json. Intentalo.

```
@foreach ($productos as $item)
    @php
        dd($item)
       //$item->name, si tienes una propiedad name dentro del JSON.
    @endphp     
@endforeach
```